# this error(c++) be in visual studio 2008

Tags: c++, debugging

this error(c++) be in visual studio 2008 what the meaning of it 
thanks in advance

```
------ Build started: Project: graphics, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
Linking...
LINK : fatal error LNK1168: cannot open E:\khraba 2\c try\graphics\Debug\graphics.exe for writing
Build log was saved at "file://e:\khraba 2\c try\graphics\graphics\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
graphics - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: It means... **cannot open E:\khraba 2\c try\graphics\Debug\graphics.exe for writing**

Comment: Some possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906404/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-d-myproj-exe

Answer (score 2):

Another process has locked the executable. And so it cannot be written to. Most likely a process is running that started from that executable. Look in task manager and when you find the process using that executable, kill it.