# Fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'sfml-graphics-s-d.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, sfml

I am getting the error shown below when I try to compile my project in Visual C++ (Visual Studio 2013).

```
1>------ Build started: Project: SFMLTest3D, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'sfml-graphics-s-d.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am very much new Visual Studio, so I used the tutorials [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/95295/) and [here](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Build-your-SFML-project-with-CMake) to set up the dependencies and everything.

At the top of my file, I have the following headers included:

```
#include <sfml.h>
```

The file `sfml.h` contains the following:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SFMLFULL_INCLUDED
#define SFMLFULL_INCLUDED

#define SFML_STATIC

#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

#if defined(_DEBUG) || defined(DEBUG)
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-graphics-s-d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-audio-s-d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-network-s-d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-window-s-d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-system-s-d.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-main-d.lib")
#else
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-graphics-s.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-audio-s.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-network-s.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-window-s.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-system-s.lib")
    #pragma comment(lib,"sfml-main.lib")
#endif

#endif // SFMLFULL_INCLUDED
```

That file is located at `..\SFML-2.3\include\sfml.h`.

The screenshot below shows the location of the `sfml-graphics-s-d.lib` file:

[image: Screenshot]

Can someone please explain what I'm missing here?  If there is any further information you need, please just let me know and I'll do my best to provide it.

**Edit:** Based on the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906404/link-fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-d-myproj-exe) I have tried several things including completely restarting my computer, but the project still won't compile.

Comment: Are you mixing 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: I don't know.  How do I find out?

Comment: Visual Studio will tell you what type of application you are building in the GUI also the Output tab looking at the build x64 = 64 bit. Win32 = 32 bit.

Comment: I just added the full output to the OP.  It is showing Win32 there, and my system is a 64 bit system.  What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: I see you are building a 32 bit application. Did you download the 32 bit sfml libraries for Visual Studio 2013? The 64 bit libs are no good for a 32 bit application.

Comment: I don't remember for sure which one I downloaded.  Is there a way to tell by looking at the source code?

Comment: I am not familiar with sfml so I can not tell you that. I did check to see there are 32 and 64 bit downloads for each of the supported compilers here: http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.3/

Comment: Okay.  I should be able to download the 32 bit version though and replace what I have with that, correct?

Comment: Actually, I just looked at chrome://downloads/ and saw that it was the 32 bit version that I downloaded.

Comment: I assume from your links above you are generating your Visual Studio project using CMake. Maybe you should look at the project settings ->Linker -> Additional Library Directories to verify that the correct path to sfml is in there.

Comment: @drescherjm I am generating my project using CMake.  According to step #9 in the first link, I'm not adding anything to the project settings --> Linker --> Additional Library Directories.  In fact, I'm not really even entirely sure whether it's correct to say that I'm generating my project with CMake since I generated a "setup" project and the settings I entered there are persisting as I create more projects. Having said all that, I did check and the paths entered according to the instructions in step #9 were entered correctly.